# PHP: What variable type does 'return;' return?

Tags: php, function, variables, types, return

Take for example the code below:

```
<?php
  function testing(){
     echo 'testing';
     return;
  }
?>
```

Based on the code above, what type of data/variable does the 'return;' statement return?

Comment: You can always do `var_dump` on the return values or the function call to test.

Comment: have you not tried it for yourself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It returns `null`. See this [Demo](https://eval.in/431934)

```
<?php
function test() {
 return;
}

var_dump(test()); // NULL
```

Comment: sure, but code is not necessary to ask a programming related question.

Comment: I think official documentation is equally appreciated. Well, almost. ;)

Answer (score 10):

> Based on the code above, what type of data/variable does the 'return;' statement return?

`null`.

From the [PHP docs on `return`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php):

> Note: If no parameter is supplied [...] NULL will be returned.

Answer (score 2):

Your code will return **NULL**

Functions which return references, may return a NULL value. This is inconsistent with the fact that function parameters passed by reference can't be passed as NULL (or in fact anything which isnt a variable).

i.e.

```
<?php

function &testRet()
{
    return NULL;
}

if (testRet() === NULL)
{
    echo "NULL";
}
?>
```

parses fine and echoes NULL